# EF Core not creating tables other then __EFMigrationsHistory

Tags: entity-framework

```
public class TokenInfoContext : DbContext
{
    public TokenInfoContext(DbContextOptions<TokenInfoContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TokenInfo> TokenInfos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TokenInfoHistory> TokenInfosHistory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TokenInfoErrorLogs> TokenInfoErrorLogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<Entity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    entry.Entity.CreatedBy = "System";
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}

// Services (Called in Program.cs)
services.AddDbContext<TokenInfoContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("conn")));

services.AddScoped<ITokenInfoRepository, TokenInfoRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITokenInfoHistoryRepository, TokenInfoHistoryRepository>();
services.AddScoped<ITokenInfoErrorLogsRepository, TokenInfoErrorLogsRepository>();

// Program.cs
app.MigrateDatabase<TokenInfoContext>((context, services) =>
{
    var logger = services.GetService<ILogger<TokenInfoContextSeed>>();
    TokenInfoContextSeed
        .SeedAsync(context, logger)
        .Wait();
});

// Repository (Same declaration for other 2 repositories)
public class TokenInfoRepository : RepositoryBase<TokenInfo>, ITokenInfoRepository
{
    public TokenInfoRepository(TokenInfoContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
    }
}

// Entities (Same declaration for other 2)
public class TokenInfo : Entity
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RefreshTokenExpiry { get; set; }
    public string Roles { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
}
```

Tables are not creating other the __EFMigrationsHistory, other three tables should be created. Database is created as MS SQL connection sting provided I am using code first approch to create tables in database. ".Net core 7.0" used to develope application. Code is writen the c# Entity Framework core 7.0.9 is used.

Comment: What you have did for creating tables? Applied migrations, does migrations have `Up` methods with create tables? Maybe you have executed `context.Database.EnsureCreated()`?